# why do I not have enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) complex list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm struggling with a list comprehension but I don't know how to deal with it. I think I understand the problem but I want to keep my one liner.
`extract_entities(content)` returns a list of tuples of 3 elements

```
[result_file_ner.write(convert_format(f'{name}\t{tag}\t{ner}\n', pos_table)) 
 for name, tag, ner in zip(*[iter(extract_entities(content))])]
```

How to change this list comprehension to keep the one liner ?
In fact I have to do that in order that I work but I'm not sure if it's a good way

```
list(map(lambda x: print(x) , zip(*[iter(extract_entities(content))])))
```

gives

```
([('Consuela', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Washington', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('longtime', 'JJ', 'O'), ('House', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('staffer', 'NN', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('an', 'DT', 'O'), ('expert', 'NN', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('securities', 'NNS', 'O'), ('laws', 'NNS', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('leading', 'VBG', 'O'), ('candidate', 'NN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('chairwoman', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Securities', 'NNPS', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('Exchange', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Commission', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Clinton', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('administration', 'NN', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Ms.', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Washington', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('44', 'CD', 'O'), ('years', 'NNS', 'O'), ('old', 'JJ', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('would', 'MD', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('first', 'JJ', 'O'), ('woman', 'NN', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('first', 'JJ', 'O'), ('black', 'JJ', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('head', 'VB', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('five-member', 'JJ', 'O'), ('commission', 'NN', 'O'), ('that', 'WDT', 'O'), ('oversees', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('securities', 'NNS', 'O'), ('markets', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Ms.', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Washington', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ("'s", 'POS', 'O'), ('candidacy', 'NN', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('being', 'VBG', 'O'), ('championed', 'VBN', 'O'), ('by', 'IN', 'O'), ('several', 'JJ', 'O'), ('powerful', 'JJ', 'O'), ('lawmakers', 'NNS', 'O'), ('including', 'VBG', 'O'), ('her', 'PRP$', 'O'), ('boss', 'NN', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Chairman', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('John', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Dingell', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('(', '(', 'O'), ('D.', 'NNP', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Mich.', 'NNP', 'O'), (')', ')', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('House', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Energy', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('Commerce', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Committee', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('She', 'PRP', 'O'), ('currently', 'RB', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('counsel', 'NN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('committee', 'NN', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Ms.', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Washington', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('Mr.', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Dingell', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('have', 'VBP', 'O'), ('been', 'VBN', 'O'), ('considered', 'VBN', 'O'), ('allies', 'NNS', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('securities', 'NNS', 'O'), ('exchanges', 'NNS', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('while', 'IN', 'O'), ('banks', 'NNS', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('futures', 'NNS', 'O'), ('exchanges', 'NNS', 'O'), ('have', 'VBP', 'O'), ('often', 'RB', 'O'), ('fought', 'VBN', 'O'), ('with', 'IN', 'O'), ('them', 'PRP', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('A', 'DT', 'O'), ('graduate', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('Harvard', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Law', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('School', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Ms.', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Washington', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('worked', 'VBD', 'O'), ('as', 'IN', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('laywer', 'NN', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('corporate', 'JJ', 'O'), ('finance', 'NN', 'O'), ('division', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('SEC', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('late', 'JJ', 'O'), ('1970s', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('She', 'PRP', 'O'), ('has', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('been', 'VBN', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('congressional', 'JJ', 'O'), ('staffer', 'NN', 'O'), ('since', 'IN', 'O'), ('1979', 'CD', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Separately', 'RB', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Clinton', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('transition', 'NN', 'O'), ('officials', 'NNS', 'O'), ('said', 'VBD', 'O'), ('that', 'IN', 'O'), ('Frank', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Newman', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('50', 'CD', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('vice', 'NN', 'O'), ('chairman', 'NN', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('chief', 'JJ', 'O'), ('financial', 'JJ', 'O'), ('officer', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('BankAmerica', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Corp.', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('expected', 'VBN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('nominated', 'VBN', 'O'), ('as', 'IN', 'O'), ('assistant', 'JJ', 'O'), ('Treasury', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('secretary', 'NN', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('domestic', 'JJ', 'O'), ('finance', 'NN', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Mr.', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Newman', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('who', 'WP', 'O'), ('would', 'MD', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('giving', 'VBG', 'O'), ('up', 'RP', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('job', 'NN', 'O'), ('that', 'WDT', 'O'), ('pays', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('$', '$', 'O'), ('1', 'CD', 'O'), ('million', 'CD', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('year', 'NN', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('would', 'MD', 'O'), ('oversee', 'VB', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Treasury', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ("'s", 'POS', 'O'), ('auctions', 'NNS', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('government', 'NN', 'O'), ('securities', 'NNS', 'O'), ('as', 'RB', 'O'), ('well', 'RB', 'O'), ('as', 'IN', 'O'), ('banking', 'NN', 'O'), ('issues', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('He', 'PRP', 'O'), ('would', 'MD', 'O'), ('report', 'VB', 'O'), ('directly', 'RB', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('Treasury', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Secretary-designate', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Lloyd', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Bentsen', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Mr.', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Bentsen', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('who', 'WP', 'O'), ('headed', 'VBD', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Senate', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Finance', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Committee', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('past', 'JJ', 'O'), ('six', 'CD', 'O'), ('years', 'NNS', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('also', 'RB', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('expected', 'VBN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('nominate', 'VB', 'O'), ('Samuel', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Sessions', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('committee', 'NN', 'O'), ("'s", 'POS', 'O'), ('chief', 'JJ', 'O'), ('tax', 'NN', 'O'), ('counsel', 'NN', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('one', 'CD', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('top', 'JJ', 'O'), ('tax', 'NN', 'O'), ('jobs', 'NNS', 'O'), ('at', 'IN', 'O'), ('Treasury', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('As', 'RB', 'O'), ('early', 'RB', 'O'), ('as', 'IN', 'O'), ('today', 'NN', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Clinton', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('camp', 'NN', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('expected', 'VBN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('name', 'VB', 'O'), ('five', 'CD', 'O'), ('undersecretaries', 'NNS', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('state', 'NN', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('several', 'JJ', 'O'), ('assistant', 'NN', 'O'), ('secretaries', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Peter', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Tarnoff', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('former', 'JJ', 'O'), ('Carter', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('administration', 'NN', 'O'), ('official', 'NN', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('president', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Council', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('on', 'IN', 'O'), ('Foreign', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Relations', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('expected', 'VBN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('named', 'VBN', 'O'), ('undersecretary', 'JJ', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('political', 'JJ', 'O'), ('affairs', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Former', 'JJ', 'O'), ('Sen.', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Tim', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Wirth', 'NNP', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('expected', 'VBN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('get', 'VB', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('newly', 'RB', 'O'), ('created', 'VBN', 'O'), ('undersecretary', 'JJ', 'O'), ('post', 'NN', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('global', 'JJ', 'O'), ('affairs', 'NNS', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('which', 'WDT', 'O'), ('would', 'MD', 'O'), ('include', 'VB', 'O'), ('refugees', 'NNS', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('drugs', 'NNS', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('environmental', 'JJ', 'O'), ('issues', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Earlier', 'RBR', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Colorado', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Democrat', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('had', 'VBD', 'O'), ('been', 'VBN', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('leading', 'VBG', 'O'), ('contender', 'NN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('head', 'VB', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Environmental', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Protection', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Agency', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('In', 'IN', 'O'), ('addition', 'NN', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Joan', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Spero', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('an', 'DT', 'O'), ('executive', 'JJ', 'O'), ('vice', 'NN', 'O'), ('president', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('American', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('Express', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Co.', 'NNP', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('leading', 'JJ', 'O'), ('candidate', 'NN', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('undersecretary', 'JJ', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('economic', 'JJ', 'O'), ('affairs', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('And', 'CC', 'O'), ('Time', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('magazine', 'NN', 'O'), ('columnist', 'NN', 'O'), ('Strobe', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Talbott', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('named', 'VBN', 'O'), ('ambassador-at-large', 'JJ', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('coordinate', 'VB', 'O'), ('U.S.', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('policy', 'NN', 'O'), ('toward', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('former', 'JJ', 'O'), ('Soviet', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('Union', 'NNP', 'I-GPE'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Several', 'JJ', 'O'), ('appointees', 'NNS', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('President', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Bush', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('are', 'VBP', 'O'), ('likely', 'JJ', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('stay', 'VB', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('office', 'NN', 'O'), ('at', 'IN', 'O'), ('least', 'JJS', 'O'), ('temporarily', 'RB', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('until', 'IN', 'O'), ('permanent', 'JJ', 'O'), ('successors', 'NNS', 'O'), ('can', 'MD', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('named', 'VBN', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('One', 'CD', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('Bernadine', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Healy', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('director', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('National', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Institutes', 'NNPS', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('Health', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Another', 'DT', 'O'), ('likely', 'JJ', 'O'), ('holdover', 'NN', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('David', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Kessler', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('head', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Food', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('Drug', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Administration', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('In', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('offfice', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('U.S.', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('Trade', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Representative-designate', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Mickey', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Kantor', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('selections', 'NNS', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('three', 'CD', 'O'), ('deputy', 'NN', 'O'), ('trade', 'NN', 'O'), ('representative', 'JJ', 'O'), ('slots', 'NNS', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('general', 'JJ', 'O'), ('counsel', 'NN', 'O'), ('are', 'VBP', 'O'), ('still', 'RB', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('decided', 'VBN', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('But', 'CC', 'O'), ('Robert', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Kyle', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Senate', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Finance', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('Committee', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ("'s", 'POS', 'O'), ('trade', 'NN', 'O'), ('counsel', 'NN', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('considered', 'VBN', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('top', 'JJ', 'O'), ('candidate', 'NN', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('one', 'CD', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('slots', 'NNS', 'O'), ('or', 'CC', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('a', 'DT', 'O'), ('trade', 'NN', 'O'), ('post', 'NN', 'O'), ('elsewhere', 'RB', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('government', 'NN', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('For', 'IN', 'O'), ('many', 'JJ', 'O'), ('subcabinet', 'NN', 'O'), ('jobs', 'NNS', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('list', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('candidates', 'NNS', 'O'), ('has', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('been', 'VBN', 'O'), ('narrowed', 'VBN', 'O'), ('considerably', 'RB', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Clinton', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('officials', 'NNS', 'O'), ('are', 'VBP', 'O'), ('said', 'VBD', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('deciding', 'VBG', 'O'), ('between', 'IN', 'O'), ('recently', 'RB', 'O'), ('retired', 'VBN', 'O'), ('Rep.', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Matthew', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('McHugh', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('(', '(', 'O'), ('D.', 'NNP', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('N.Y.', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), (')', ')', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('environmental', 'JJ', 'O'), ('activist', 'NN', 'O'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('transition', 'NN', 'O'), ('official', 'NN', 'O'), ('Gus', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Speth', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('director', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Agency', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('International', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Development', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Among', 'IN', 'O'), ('others', 'NNS', 'O'), ('expected', 'VBN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('hired', 'VBN', 'O'), ('include', 'VBP', 'O'), ('Kitty', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Higgins', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('an', 'DT', 'O'), ('aide', 'NN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('Michigan', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Rep.', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Sander', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Levin', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('as', 'IN', 'O'), ('chief', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('staff', 'NN', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Labor', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Department', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('while', 'IN', 'O'), ('Jerry', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Palast', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Service', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Employees', 'NNPS', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('International', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Union', 'NNP', 'I-ORGANIZATION'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('expected', 'VBN', 'O'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('department', 'NN', 'O'), ("'s", 'POS', 'O'), ('director', 'NN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('legislative', 'JJ', 'O'), ('affairs', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('Separately', 'RB', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('incoming', 'VBG', 'O'), ('Clinton', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('administration', 'NN', 'O'), ('is', 'VBZ', 'O'), ('seriously', 'RB', 'O'), ('considering', 'VBG', 'O'), ('moving', 'VBG', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('briefing', 'NN', 'O'), ('room', 'NN', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('press', 'NN', 'O'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('decades', 'NNS', 'O'), ('situated', 'VBN', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('West', 'NNP', 'B-LOCATION'), ('Wing', 'NNP', 'I-LOCATION'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('White', 'NNP', 'B-FACILITY'), ('House', 'NNP', 'I-FACILITY'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('out', 'IN', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('White', 'NNP', 'B-FACILITY'), ('House', 'NNP', 'I-FACILITY'), ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('into', 'IN', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('Old', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), ('Executive', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Office', 'NNP', 'O'), ('Building', 'NNP', 'O'), ('next', 'JJ', 'O'), ('door', 'NN', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
([('The', 'DT', 'O'), ('current', 'JJ', 'O'), ('briefing', 'NN', 'O'), ('room', 'NN', 'O'), ('could', 'MD', 'O'), ('be', 'VB', 'O'), ('used', 'VBN', 'O'), ('for', 'IN', 'O'), ('staff', 'NN', 'O'), ('offices', 'NNS', 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')],)
```

```
[[result_file_ner.write(convert_format(f'{name}\t{tag}\t{ner}\n', pos_table)) 
  for name, tag, ner in line]
 for line in extract_entities(content)]
```

How to access to that?

Comment: It's impossible for us to debug this without being able to reproduce it. Please read [mcve] and [edit] your question.

Comment: I don't know what you intend for the `zip` to do here, but `zip(*[...])` is really useless when the `...` is just a single expression. There is no need to use `zip` if you have a sequence of 3-tuples and you want to destructure them when you iterate.

Comment: As nice as one liners are, they're sometimes just too dense and are often just better as multiple lines, certainly from a readability point of view.  Boot up a python shell, execute `import this` and have a read.  Nice to revisit this every year or so.

Comment: What is more important, that the code is comprehensible, that it works, or that it's one line? Why is it so important that the code is one line? Do you think it's more "efficient"? More "Pythonic"? Or some other reason?

Comment: i think it's understandable in one line

Comment: _i think it's understandable in one line_ -- well, you would be wrong.  The fact that you're having this problem is an example of that.  Remember that code is READ much more often than it is WRITTEN.  Clever code is much harder to maintain later on.

Comment: yes but i code for myself. I can adapt my code when i work with people. Prog is also fun.

Comment: _I can adapt my code when I work with people_: Well, that would be now. As multiple others have already mentioned, this one-liner is extremely dense and very hard to read.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `iter(<list>)`, what with `*[<expression>]`?

Comment: get a flatten list of tuples of 3 elements, unzipped into 3 variables at the end to write them together in the right order in a file. not list of list of tuples. Now it's clearer, isn't it ?

Comment: `Now it's clearer, isn't it?` Nowhere near clear enough for me, as I don't know what of part of code to associate with what part of prose. Let me try to start from the other end and present what I see in the code: `[<expression>]` makes a *list* of `<expression>`. A list is an *iterable*, and `*`  as a prefix operator unpacks an iterable: this combination does little more than parenthesise `<expression>`. `iter(<expression>)` returns a single object supporting `__iter__()`. It is very difficult to tell what you are trying to achieve while you try to present that with Python code not mastered.

Comment: It may be as simple as `(result_file_ner.write(convert_format(f'{name}\t{tag}\t{ner}\n', pos_table)) 
 for name, tag, ner in extract_entities(content))`.